# i can't find error in logic of this selection sorting . it prints out default array in same order

Tags: c++, sorting

```cpp
int arr[] = {22, 0, 45, 32, 12, 78, 89};

int size= sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

cout << size << endl;

int temp =arr[0];
```

Temp variable is not returning new updated array members; it is returning the default array and not a new sorted array in ascending order.

```cpp
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
  int temp = arr[i];
  for (int j=i+1; j<size; j++) {
    if (temp > arr[j]) {
      temp=arr[j];
    }
  }
  arr[i]=temp;
  cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: How do you know what `temp` does or does not return? You never print `temp`, or elements of `arr2`. You print elements of `arr`, which are never updated and so of course preserve their original values.

Comment: temp value is updating . via comparison isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but you are not printing `temp`, or any values that `temp` may affect.

Comment: yeah i see , i've updated  the question.

Comment: The current code should print the minimum element of the tail portion of `arr`, starting at position `i`. It should print 0 two times, then 12 three times, then 78 and 89. Is this not what you expect? Is this not what you observe?

Comment: So far this code has near-nothing to do with selection sort. First, you want to retain the *index* leading to your critical value (the smallest value if you're sorting ascending, the greatest value if you're sorting descending). You're not doing that (you're retaining the value, not the index). Then, when you finish the inner j-loop, that index will refer to the item you want to swap with `arr[i]`. The only thing you seem to have so far is two loops and a comparison.

Comment: yeah i understand logical fallay , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

'''

```
int arr[]={22,0,45,32,12,78,89};

int size= sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

cout<<size<<endl;


for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    int temp =arr[i];
```

'''
in the inner loop temp value will be swapped so the older compared value does not repeat itself.
'''
for(int j=i+1 ; j<size-1;j++){

```
    if (temp>arr[j]){
        temp=arr[j];
        arr[j]=arr[i];
        arr[i]=temp;
        
        }
        
    }
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
}
}
```

'''

Comment: That's not how selection sort works, but at least you're doing something resembling sorting.

Comment: I know how it  works , and now have written a code by myself to show.

Comment: what change might you suggest sir

Comment: Actually doing selection sort would be a good start, if your question title is the actual goal. Selection sort isn't about remember what a "greatest" or "least" value is; it's about remembering *where to find it*. Though an O(N^2) algorithm, selection sort will trigger *at most* (N-1) swaps for a sequence of N length. It's honestly one of the only redeeming attributes of the algorithm. If your underlying data type is cheap to compare, but expensive to swap, *and* the sequence is reasonably short, selection sort may be a viable option.

Comment: so want to swap pointers instead of real values .  time complexity is  a problem here i understand  but it will dpend on the order of given list .

Comment: For [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), it does *not* depend on the order of the given list. it is *always* O(N^2) comparisons, and at-worst (N-1) swaps. The [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) even has a C implementation that describes exactly what I'm telling you.